# How to update the nodes in the hash Map in specific key in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, hashmap

I want to remove all even nodes from the linked list. How can I update the node in the specific key of the hashmap? `H.get(0).next=temp` is not working. The desired output is 2 4, but I'm not getting it.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    head = new Node(1);
    head.next = new Node(2);
    head.next.next = new Node(3);
    head.next.next.next = new Node(4);
    head.next.next.next.next = new Node(5);
    Node temp=head;
    HashMap<Integer,Node>H=new HashMap<>();
        while(temp!=null) {
            if(temp.data%2==0) {
                if(!H.containsKey(0)) {
                    H.put(0, temp);
                } else {
                    //This statement is not working
                    H.get(0).next=temp;  
                }
            }
        temp=temp.next;
        }
        head=H.get(0);
        while(temp!=null) {
            System.out.print(temp.data);
            temp=temp.next;
    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working and what is the error?

Comment: What is the use of `HashMap` here?

Comment: I want to  store the nodes in the specific key of hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the last loop, you wrote `while(temp!=null){` but the `temp` is null after the loop and doesn't reference the head.
- I don't see the value in using `HashMap` here.

Here's what we can do **to remove all nodes with even data**:

```
Node head;
head = new Node(1);
head.next = new Node(2);
head.next.next = new Node(3);
head.next.next.next = new Node(4);
head.next.next.next.next = new Node(5);

Node oddTail = null, curr = head;

while (curr != null) {
    if (curr.data % 2 != 0) { // Odd data
        if(oddTail != null){
            oddTail.next = curr; // Update oddTail
        }

        oddTail = curr;
    }

    curr = curr.next;
}

if(oddTail != null){ // The oddTail.next might point to a node with even data
    oddTail.next = null; 
} else{
    head = null; // No nodes with odd data
}

curr = head;

// Print the list
while(curr != null){
    System.out.println(curr.data);
    curr = curr.next;
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't need a HashMap when doing operations on a Linked List, you just have to keep the reference of the nodes and remove them accordingly.
I think something like this should work.

As you see I don't have the referenced stored in a HashMap but what I try to do is to explore from the head to the tail, keeping a reference of the previous node I explored. Why? Because when I find an even node I want to be connect the previous node to the next one such that I remove the current node. I have the edge case of when the even node is the head because there is no previous node assigned.

Wasn't really able to try this code but maybe works as a reference for what you're trying to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    head=new Node(1);
    head.next=new Node(2);
    head.next.next=new Node(3);
    head.next.next.next=new Node(4);
    head.next.next.next.next=new Node(5);

    Node current = head;
    Node prev = null;
    while(current != null){
        if(current.data%2==0){
            if(current == head){
              head = current.next;
            } else {
              prev.next = current.next;
              current = current.next;
            }
        } else {
            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    
    current = head
    while(current!=null){
        System.out.print(current.data);
        current=current.next;
    }
}
```